# How to display hardcoded string of API level in android textview

Tags: android, string, textview

So I am trying to add a TextView widget to my app that reports the API level that my device is running to the user.

I found out this string reports the API Level:

```
String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Unfortunately after some more research, it seems like most people are very passionate about not using hardcoded strings in Android and it appears that it is not allowed. However, I kind of need to because it is essential to display the API level of the device.

If someone could tell me how to display hardcoded strings or use string resources somehow to display the API level to the user, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: That's not a hard-coded string. A hard-coded string would be something like "This is my string". It also only returns official Android version numbers, so I don't think there would ever be any localization on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a String resource like this:

```
<string name="wine_detail_header">Wine Details</string>
```

inside string.xml in values folder. You can then use it like this:

```
String s = myContext.getResources().getString(R.string.wine_detail_header);
```

Comment: how to make it appear in my textview though? Because I want to take the value of androidOS and put it in the stringsxml

Comment: You cannot modify strings.xml at runtime. Instead you can use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is perfectly fine. `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` is what is known as a constant not a hard-coded string.

Comment: how to make it appear in my textview though? Because I want to take the value of androidOS and put it in the stringsxm

Comment: You won't be able to set this string in XML. You will need to set it in code. In your Activity's onCreate() method after you call setContentView you can do a findViewById to get a reference to your TextView then call `tv.setText(Build.VERSION.RELEASE)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setText()` method of `TextView`:

```
myTextView.setText(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```